# Sails: 404 pages won't use the default layout?

Tags: sails.js

In sails.js, all files that are in the views folder use layout.ejs as their template.
Error pages like 404.ejs won't use layout.ejs for some reason.

I couldn't find any setting for that, can I change it?

Thanks!

A link to the repository, if needed:
http://github.com/ronenteva/MySkills

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sails v0.10.x uses the `notFound` response to serve the 404 page, equivalent to calling `res.notFound()` in a controller action.  A default response handler is provided for you in `api/responses/notFound.js`, but you can customize it to do anything you like, including using `res.view()` to serve the 404 page with a layout.  The default code uses `res.render` rather than `res.view`, because the default `404.ejs` has its own layout.

Docs for custom responses are [here](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Custom-Responses).

In Sails v0.9, you can edit the `views/404.ejs` file, and then `config/404.js` file to use `res.view` instead of `res.render` if you'd like your updated `404.ejs` to use your default layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the link at the end seems broken.

Answer (score 1):

As I was on the same problem, but for the 403 error, I found your post.
Unfortunately, since Sails 0.11, things have changed, and this solution doesn't work anymore...

After some work on it, the solution is very simple.
Just edit the corresponding `.js` file (`forbidden.js`, `notFound.js`, etc. in the `api/responses` folder), to add, before any `return` call (why not just after the `res.status()`, mmmh?), this :

`res.locals.layout = 'myLayout';`

Supposing you named your layout file `myLayout.ejs`.

If you prefer to use the default layout, replace `'myLayout'` by `false`.

And here it is :)